# How can I process custom exception from server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My server always retrun JSON object. If error occurs it is also set response status to 300.

I handle my sucess reponse with

```
    $.getJSON("url", function(data){
alert(data.message) 
})
```

and it is works fine.
But my exceptional case show undefined? how can I get my json reponse object?

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(data) { 
alert(data.message) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i alway have problem with $.getJSON and $.ajax. Then i change my code to

```
$("div").load(url, function(response, stts, xhr){ alert(response);});
```

and never have any ajax problem again.

edit

i use to have problem with $.ajax $.get etc... then i try to figure out the reason. i found out it has so many reason y it's failed. such as parameter passing, conflict with updatePanel(asp.net), etc. so i alway add  at the end of pages when i want to get only some specific data. its easier, quicker, cachable result, easier to detect error.

Comment: You should be calling `$.ajax`, not `load`.  (Unless you're actually loading HTML into every `<div>` on your page.

Comment: i alway leave div display:none for loading stuff. something like $("div:not(:visible):last.loader").load